# How to create flavors for few apps in one project

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I've got a problem with project flavors configuration.

I want to define project structure like this:

Three Applications (with very similar functions) flavours with free & pro version each, it means there will be 6 apps versions:
- A(pro, free)
- B(pro, free)
- C(pro, free).

And now for example, I build project B (free version) and merge resources with B (pro version). When resource from B (free version) is missing, then take it from pro version, and then when it's also missing, get default resources from main.

Important thing is every version for example A (free) and A (pro) have some different resources (for example: application icon, logo etc.)

Actually I've got something like this, but it doesn't work as I want to.

```
    productFlavors {
    aPro {
        applicationId "com.example.apro"
    }

    aFree {
        applicationId "com.example.afree"
    }

    bPro {
        applicationId "com.example.bpro"
    }

    bFree {
        applicationId "com.example.bfree"
    }

    cPro {
        applicationId "com.example.cpro"
    }

    cFree {
        applicationId "com.example.cfree"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did in your `build.gradle` file is correct. Other than gradle configuration in your gradle file, you need to add folders under your `app/src` folder. So the project structure is like this:

```
  Project
|---- app
|     |---- build
|     |---- libs
|     |---- src
|           |---- aPro
|           |---- aFree
|           |---- bPro
|           |---- bFree
|           |---- cPro
|           |---- cFree
|           |---- main
```

Under the main folder, there is your main code, e.g. functions, methods, resources.

Under the `productFlavorName` folder, you can add resources folder, add the application icons, logo etc.

Then, in Android Studio, open `Build Variants` tab (in the left bar of the Android Studio, vertically), choose a `Build Variant` to debug.

More details in [this official document](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants).

Comment: I know how to create a structure like yours and it will works, but not the way as I want it. Your solution will cause duplication of some resources that are the same in free and pro version, for example strings or ui graphics. And that is not correct way.

Comment: @Skalaw You should move the duplicated resources to `main` folder

Comment: So if I have this 3 applications (6 versions) in one project and for example aPro and aFree have the same ui "primary_color" in colors.xml but bPro and bFree have different colors. So i should put the same colors.xml file to aPro and aFree resources folder or there is a way to merge colors.xml between this two versions of one app?

Comment: @Skalaw You should put the same colors in one `color.xml` file in `main/res/values` folder, put the different colors in separate `color.xml` files under variants' resources folder.

Comment: ok, I understand this, but is there a way to read resources like this :

aFree/res -> aPro/res -> main/res/...

I just want to put one more default folder between aFree and main resources. It will give me a solution to not duplicate the same values in two modules.

Comment: @Skalaw No, it doesn't fall back like this.